# What Happens to Local Changes When an Admin Forces Unlock a Specific File?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and TFS source control.

Imagine i checked out a file and added a line of code and leaved the office without checking in. Someone else needed to make a change in this specific file but cannot check out because it is locked on me. An admin used TFS command line tools or something else and undoed my lock on this file to allow the second person to make the changes.

The question is that in this case, what happens to the file in my computer? Is the line i added deleted or still there but i cannot check in since the lock has been undoed and i need to get latest version and add the line again?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use? Are you going to use [local workspace or server workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops)?

Comment: I am using server workspace and TFS 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A check-out lock prevents users who are using **server workspace** from checking out and making changes to the locked item in their workspaces. In Team Foundation Server 2012 and later, check-out locks are generally not effective because of **local workspace**.

Assuming you are using **server workspace**, for your scenario, the file on your computer won't be changed. When you want to open the file on your computer, you'll get the following item to let you choose server version or workspace version.

[image]